# Java won't open the correct file, constantly returns the File Not Found Exception even when using the absolute path

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I'm unable to open a file in java, using the eclipse IDE, and when I print the file.getAbsolutePath() it is identical to where the file is located. 
https://gyazo.com/687f73add6c7122c3095db546abc0e28
This is the directory, and I'm working in alice.java trying to access alice2.txt. I've also refreshed the page many times, and tried linking with file to the absolute path actually given to where it is looking and it is still unable to open the file.

When I print the tester.getAbsolutePath(), and then input the absolute path into my file explorer, it instantly opens the appropriate text document, so my understanding is that it is looking in the right spot, but for some reason cannot open that file. 
Here is the code I'm using to open the file:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File tester = new File("alice2.txt");

    //System.out.println(tester.getAbsolutePath());

    Scanner in = new Scanner(tester);

    in.close();
}
```

I'm new to using eclipse, I've only used NetBeans before, so I apologize if I'm doing something really dumb and not realizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the file is absolute to your project. In your case `HomeWOrk_one`
so if you want to access alice2.txt try `"./alice2.txt"` or for alice.txt `./src/com/abenson/hw0/three/alice.txt`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
File tester = new File("./alice2.txt");  // or new File("./src/com/abenson/hw0/three/alice.txt");

System.out.println(tester.getAbsolutePath());

Scanner in = new Scanner(tester);
System.out.println(in.hasNext());
in.close();
```

}

Comment: The second suggestions seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

whith `new File("file.txt");` he try found the file on the racine of the project [image: see here]

he try found the blue file not the red

Answer (score 0):

You took the right approach which is to print the absolute path. IMO the only reasonable explanation is that you did not put enough attention to checking it. Can you try to re-run it and compare the paths: the one printed and the one you see right clicking and checking file properties?

Typically the output of the program will be on most setups:
`<your_workspace_path>\<your_project_path>\alice2.txt`
whereas you want
`<your_workspace_path>\<your_project_path>\src\fr\test\alice2.txt`